# MySQL, how can I select conversations from a list of messages

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code:

```
SELECT a.id, a.to_id, a.from_id, a.seen, a.date, a.message

FROM  `Chat_messages` a

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(  `id` ) AS id
    FROM  `Chat_messages` AS  `alt` 
    WHERE  `alt`.`to_id` =7
    OR  `alt`.`from_id` =7
    GROUP BY  `to_id` ,  `from_id`
)b ON a.id = b.id
```

returning:

[image]

So, I want to get conversations (sent and received messages) of an user and latest message of it. 
Latest message works ok, but the problem is that I get 2 rows from messages received (#1 and #2) and 2 rows from messages sent (#3 and #4), but I only need 2 results, because there are 2 conversations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group by least(to_id, from_id), greatest(to_id, from_id)` to make sure conversions between 2 people are merged:

```
SELECT a.id, a.to_id, a.from_id, a.seen, a.date, a.message

FROM  `Chat_messages` a

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(  `id` ) AS id
    FROM  `Chat_messages` AS  `alt` 
    WHERE  `alt`.`to_id` =7
    OR  `alt`.`from_id` =7
    GROUP BY  least(`to_id` ,  `from_id`), greatest(`to_id` ,  `from_id`)
)b ON a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to pick out the row that holds the latest sent message and the row that holds the latest received message respectively, is using the row_number() window function. Unfortunately, MySql does not support window functions, so I think it's best to use two nested SELECT's:

```
SELECT z.id, max(z.to_id), max(z.from_id), max(z.seen), max(z.date), max(z.message)
FROM chat_messages z
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT x.from_id, max(date) date
FROM chat_messages x
GROUP BY x.from_id) f
ON z.from_id = f.from_id AND z.date = f.date
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT y.to_id, max(date) date
FROM chat_messages y
GROUP BY y.to_id) t
ON z.to_id = t.to_id AND z.date = t.date
GROUP BY z.id
```

I do not recommend using max on ID's if you care about correctness in the long run.

Comment: Thank you, but I get  #1054 - Unknown column 't.date' in 'on clause' any idea? Thank you for the max on ID, tip. I missed that.

Comment: Forgot to name the max column. Fixed it now. I think it will return no rows now though. You need to use left joins and then remove null values with max functions on all columns in the outer select. I'll update in a minute.

Comment: Just updated the answer. This was what I could come up with quickly, cause I need to sleep now. Hopes it helps!